# Add new column to multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I would like to perform an identical operation on multiple dataframes - for example, divide column "A" by 1000 and write as new column called "Calculation".  I've found many answers to similar questions using mapply and lapply on a list of dataframes, but they don't change the actual dataframes, only the items in the list.
I want to modify the *original* dataframes.  Also, there may be hundreds of dataframes to perform the operation on.

For example, original dataframes:

```
df1
A
1
2
3
4
5

df2
A
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Desired output:

```
df1
A   Calculation
1   0.001
2   0.002
3   0.003
4   0.004
5   0.005

df2
A   Calculation
10  0.01
11  0.011
12  0.012
13  0.013
14  0.014
15  0.015
```

It seems like this should be very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you add what has failed?

Comment: Try `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(Calc=A/1000)` using package `dplyr`.

Comment: `df$new_col <- df1$column / df2$column`?(assumes equal lengths). If you have several `data.frame`s, use a function with target columns and "parent" data frame then `map` that to all or use some `merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the dataframes in a list using `mget`. If your data is called `df1`, `df2` you can construct the string of dataframe names using `paste0`. For more complicated names you can use a particular pattern to find dataframes (something like `df\\d+` meaning `df` followed by a number).

Once the data is in a list you can perform the calculation that you want using `lapply` which returns a list back.

```
new_list <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:2)), transform, Calculation = A/100)
```

To get the changed dataframe with new column in original dataframe use `list2env`.

```
list2env(new_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak!  This is terrific.  I think I saw you answer pretty much all the similar questions I found on stack overflow, but without

        list2env(new_list, .GlobalEnv)

, which solves it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the fact you use lapply on the data.frame instead of a list of data.frame :

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 10:15)

df_list <- list(df1, df2)
lapply(df_list, function(.x) mutate(.x, calculation = X / 1000))
```

This code return the list of desired data.frame

If you want to do it in place (with copy though) you can add an assignement after the mutate or you can do it with data.table :

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(x = 1:5)
df2 <- data.table(x = 10:15)

df_list <- list(df1, df2)
lapply(df_list, function(.x) .x[, calculation := X / 1000])
```